# Unable to execute dex

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had the following problem after I added a .jar file into my android project:

" Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space "

After I changed the eclipse.ini file to the following. As in this post:

[Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?lq=1)

I receive the following error:

--Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65662 into a non-jumbo instruction!

--Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65662 into a non-jumbo instruction

Please can someone help me to figure this out or encountered the similar problem??

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

This is my eclipse.ini file right now:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of version controlling?

Comment: No. It's a PhoneGap project. I'm using cordova - 2.2.0 version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Error in Eclipse: "Unable to execute dex: Cannot merge new index 65799 into a non-jumbo instruction!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439882/android-error-in-eclipse-unable-to-execute-dex-cannot-merge-new-index-65799-i)

Answer (score 2):

Added   `dex.force.jumbo=true`    into my project.properties and that did the trick. (make sure you have ADTv21+, you also need to clean project once.)