# Can't debug old android app that I wrote - INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED Error

Tags: android

After I wiped my phone I can't install or even debug an app on my phone that I wrote.
I get this error:

```
[2013-05-15 09:20:40 - BatteryMonitor] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED
[2013-05-15 09:20:40 - BatteryMonitor] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-05-15 09:20:40 - BatteryMonitor] Launch canceled!
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
Logcat: W/PackageManager( 2277): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.ck.batterymonitor-1.apk

Comment: Did you look for the solutions in the other questions about this? Seems to me this is an eclipse issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338242/eclipse-installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed/12662787#12662787

Comment: No this is not the case. I can't install even from the device and the logcat that I get is not the same as their

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:-

- **Uninstall the previous version of the app** from the emulator/phone first,
  then try again. You can do this by visiting *System Settings >
  Applications > Manage Applications* and selecting the app.
- Delete the package name folder in **/data/data** (if you are using a
  *actual device you should have root access* , if you are using emulator
  just *wipe data before opening emulator* or make a new AVD)

Hope this helps

Comment: I alredy deleted the app.
Can I delete data files without root access?

Comment: No,In actual device you require root access to delete package name folder in **/data/data**