# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have this error every time that I intend to install the app on my device with Eclipse Juno.

**Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED**

I also tried uninstalling the app, clearing the project, reopening Eclipse and reboot de system and the phone.

and the problem is still there.

the logcat said
**No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/STU.apk**
but I don't understand what he said (Eclipse) about this.

I don't know what to do now.

please help

[image]

EDIT:
Added AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="amalgame.trainer.ultimate"
      android:versionName="1" android:versionCode="1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="false"
    />

    <application      
        android:allowBackup="true"      
        android:icon="@drawable/iconfree4848"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
        android:logo="@drawable/iconfree4848"
        >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="amalgame.trainer.ultimate.TrainerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"

            ....
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Put your androidmanifest.xml file over here

Comment: here same http://stackoverflow.com/a/12662787/1835231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have  got the solution after the several tries, the solution was reset to factory settings the phone and problem solved.
It's not a good solution but this solve my problem.

Comment: the real thing was delete the app folfer from de device. In my case I need to have root the phone.

Answer (score 1):

After Restart the android device and delete the package folder from the device. my problem solved.

Comment: HOw to deleete the package folder on the device?

Comment: m sure, @user1182201 must be talking about a rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue - This should cover your problem :)

[Eclipse Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338242/eclipse-installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed)

I've also had this problem before -
te most reliable solution is to wipe the Emulator using.

```
emulator.exe -avd myAvdName -wipe-data
```

Greetings

Christopher

Comment: thanks but I'm using the device phone (Razr i) , How I supposed to fix (wipe-data) on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete app data from the device and the problem was solved.
Use the rm command with caution, make sure your app/package name is correct.

```
adb shell
cd /data/data
rm -rf com.company.appname
```

Comment: Device must be rooted for this solution