# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED no root

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have checked all the solutions, comments and answers of all other questions in StackOverflow.

I have been running, compiling and debugging my app for months. But suddenly it started to appear this message in my Eclipse when using my Nexus to play with it.

MOBILE:

- I have no root !!! (It's a Nexus, and I have no root, and all the answers in other Stackoverflow's questions need root to be executed)
- The application is uninstalled, there's no trace of it in "Applications"
- Since I don't have root access, I can not access to /data/data folder, or /data/local, or /data
- I *do* know problem would be solved resetting the phone to factory settings, but, sincerely, I can not.

ECLIPSE:

- I have cleaned the project many times, restart Eclipse and even update it
- I can not change the name of the project (as one solution suggests), since it's a long time project and I can not change it
- Console says:

  - Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED
  - Please check logcat output for more details.
  - Launch canceled!
- Logcat says:

  - 01-05 12:18:19.265: W/ActivityManager(761): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk
  - 01-05 12:18:20.855: W/PackageManager(761): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.myapp-1.apk
- I can install, uninstall other APK/applications with no problems at all. So it's not about permissions in /data folder/subfolders

CONSOLE:

- If I try to uninstall (with -d or any other parameter) the app it says: "Failure" (because adb does not find the app in the phone)

So, I'm not debugging with virtual machine / emulator. I have a Nexus no-rooted with no trace of the application, and I can not build the app from Eclipse to the device.

Thank you

Comment: I have the exact same issue right now. I now have 2 devices that I can't deploy to. This has happened to me once before; I was only able to resolve the issue after a factory reset. I do not want to do that this time of course.

Comment: I can't believe a factory reset is the solution to a properly bug like this one.

Comment: Agreed. I'm still looking into a solution. Until then, I had to get my device back up and running.

Comment: Have you modified the android:sharedUserId field in your app Manifest? If so, I assume you've already read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338242/eclipse-installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed

Comment: Yes anddev84 ... I tried also that.

Comment: tried all the solution below, not working for me, consider of reset to factory

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue in my **non-rooted Nexus 5**. I managed to solve it **without root access nor Factory reset**.

For this device, I managed to solve it by going to `Settings -> Storage -> Misc` and try to delete any files related to the faulty app (in my case, an .apk that was pushed from Android Studio and a .db file). I also clicked on `Cached data` to wipe the cache for all apps.

I don't know exactly which of the two things triggered the solution. You probably want to try to delete some files in `Misc` before wiping the cached data, since it seems less of an overkill.

It seems to be that there were some remaining files from a previous installation which weren't wiped with the uninstall (probably [an issue in the Android installation system](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65790)). These files aren't accessible without root access, since they are under the /data/local/ folder. Apparently the Storage tools for the Nexus 5 have permission to delete files under that folder.

I don't know whether other devices have a similar set of storage tools.

Comment: I changed the gradle version i was working with to  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc3'

Comment: clear `Misc` works for me . after remove all the file in `Misc`,  everything is ok

Answer (score 5):

Downloading app from play store will resolve the issue.
To continue development on the app, uninstall the currently installed app and just launch the app from eclipse.

It works fine.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I think Android studio failed midway uninstalling the old app and installing then uninstalling from the play store seems to have cleared any left over data properly.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem odd, but my pointy-haired boss just had this issue and tried everything we could think of.  Just would NOT install due to the INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED error.

He uninstalled some other apps (games) and suddenly it would install.  Maybe it is an issue of disk space on internal card?  Dunno, but worth a try when someone else hits it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. On HTC One M8 (4.4.2) unrooted

Comment: I dont know how this worked or what happened, but i was one click away of factory reset when i tried this and it worked. Your point hair boss is the best

Answer (score 3):

First time this happened I tried installing from eclipse, from command line etc....
Everything failed so I did a factory reset which then worked.

24 hours later it happened again.

Not wanting to do another factory reset, I tried all the same things again to no avail.

Lastly I tried downloading our current app from the appstore, which miraculously worked.

I then used adb to reinstall.

So if you have a version of your app in the app store, try installing that to get something on your phone, then do a reinstall "adb -d install -r $PACKAGE.apk

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I tried all other solutions but this worked on my Sony Xperia Z unrooted, thanks.

Comment: I tried same thing; play store shows: Can't install app message with error code: -24

Answer (score 2):

This (or some other magic) helped me:

```
adb shell pm clear MY_PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Just got "Failed". On HTC One M8 (4.4.2) unrooted

Comment: @KarimVarela have you solved the problem? Got the same "Failed" (Galaxy S3 4.3)

Comment: This worked for me:

adb install -l -r <'apk_name'>.apk 

-l = forward lock

-r = reinstall

Comment: @Karim Varela: your solution worked for me, too - finally, after trying everything else I have found on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this like below without rooting on my Nexus 5.

- Push your app to /sdcard/
- adb push test.apk /sdcard/
- adb shell
- adb shell pm install -l /sdcard/test.apk

-l option means - pm install: installs a package to the system.  Options:
    -l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.

Comment: Not working, still getting `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]`

Comment: This actually worked for me, can't believe it after everything else failed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other things to check/try that are safe to do:

- Make sure your package name is 100% unique and not colliding with
  another app. You could temporarily change it to test.
- Try powering your phone off and then back on to clear
  data caches.
- Try a soft reset for your device (which might be the
  same as powering off/on).

Comment: For me a simple reboot did the trick. Afterwards "adb install package.apk"

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting Cached Data under `Settings -> Storage`, this will clear all cached App data at once, but it does the job (in my case)

Comment: Worked first try with this for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of if you have install the app with same package name. So try to remove that one.

Answer (score 0):

I could only fix this by rooting.  I know you don't want to do that, but it worked for me.  I downloaded Titanium Backup then found my uninstalled app crossed out in the list on Titanium Backup.  I couldn't get rid of that crossed out one until I went to Batch Actions then Remove orphan data.  That allowed me to re-install my app and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

adb install -l -r <'apk_name'>.apk

-l = forward lock

-r = reinstall

Comment: didn't work. i think there are corrupt files under data dir. i can't access without root. here is the error:     Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

Comment: not work. same as others `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.  What finally worked for me was to change the `applicationId` (your package name) in `build.gradle` to something different, then rebuild the project, and voilà, successful deployment.

What led to this situation was that I'd copied an existing Android Studio project into a new one, and was working off of that new one.  The thing is, I'd never deployed the original apk on my device before, and was only trying to deploy the new copy of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a device that was just for testing, so I just reset the whole device. It worked for me anywho.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Put your APK to the device's storage/sd card
2. `adb shell pm install -l -r "/sdcard/<apk_filename>.apk"`

-l = forward lock
-r = reinstall

Answer (score 0):

For **no root** Device you need you need to delete the app from the app list in the device:

1. go to "settings"
2. go to "storage"
3. on third tab "downloaded apps" locate your app
4. you can delete it from there

Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the package name of the GCM signature worked. since it uninstalls the complete package.

[For more detailed explination click here](http://androidcodelab.com/errors/android-error-installation-error-install_failed_uid_changed-fix)

```
<permission
        android:name="com.androidcodelab.sampleproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.androidcodelab.sampleproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

Package name of the project changed to :

```
<permission
        android:name="com.androidcodelab.xyz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidcodelab.xyz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

and then I reverted back to the actual package name

Answer (score 0):

For android studio go to **File**-> **Project Structure** -> **app** -> **Flavors** and your right side you will see **Application Id** field just change Application Id and you are ready to go... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Run/debug configurations.
2. Under Android App delete "app".
3. Then add another configuration under module: app

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For me the only way was to root the phone and clear /data/data/ directory. Here are the steps:
1. Open web browser on mobile device
2. Open website: https://towelroot.com/
3. Click on lambda sign to download Towerl Root and install it afterwards
4. Open Towel root app and click on button "make it rain". If it says: "device not compatible" google other wait to root the device.
5. Download SuperSU app from Play Store
6. Download Terminal Emulator app from Play Store
7. Run Terminal Emulator
8. Type following command in terminal emulator:
    **su**
9. Allow superuser access for terminal emulator
10.Type following command in terminal emulator, substitute 'package_name' with your app's package name:
    **rm -r /data/data/package_name**

Answer (score -1):

I tried all above and NADA!

the ONLY way it works for me *(NON ROOTED DEVICE)* was:

1.- Change on **Project structure** [Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S]->**Flavors**: the **Application Id**, for example:
'com.example.something' to 'com.example.somethingxx'.
(which is the same as changing on the build.gradle file)

2.- **Refactor package name** of the project to the **SAME NEW NAME** you used on Application Id: 'com.example.somethingxx'

This will ensure you are installing a new App on the device... let me know!

Comment: I can't change neither ApplicationId nor package name, because I already have an app published in GooglePlay with customers using a paid version.