# Android Studio: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am running into a rather annoying error trying to install (and run) my application using Android Studio (version 1.0.1). First it says it finds another application with the same package name but different signature on the device (Verizon Samsung S4) so I hit continue to uninstall application before trying to install the 'new' one. I get "Unknown failure". Then I try again and instead of recognizing another application on the device I just get Failure: [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]. There are plenty of threads out there with this exact same question, however, the only two solutions are either A) delete data files that require a rooted device, or B) factory reset the device. Neither of those will work for my situation. Does anyone have any insight as to how to fix this WITHOUT the above recommendations from other threads?

I should also add that there is NO VISIBLE TRACE of the application anywhere on my device (other than possibly in data files, but again, I am NOT rooted). This is only the second install ever onto the device and I have no idea what changed between this time and the first time. It would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** For anyone that comes across this, the only solution we found was renaming the package name and then after installing and uninstalling the app, we renamed the package back to its original and we never saw this error again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android INSTALL\_FAILED\_UID\_CHANGED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed)

Comment: @krossovochkin That post is inactive and the only solution on there requires a rooted device. I clearly state this above...

Comment: There are a couple suggestions on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932848/installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed-no-root?rq=1) that don't require root.  Please try those and update this question.

Comment: krossovochkin's link worked for me - for me it similarly was a folder in /data/data/ that existed and hence didn't allow the app to install. I'm afraid without root you won't be able to delete that folder...