# Is there any way to upgrade an Android app by adding android: sharedUserId in the manifest, without uninstalling the app so the data gets persisted

Tags: android

In manifest I put android:sharedUserId="xxxx.xxxx.xxxx" and android:sharedUserLabel="@string/shared_user_label"

```
<manifest package="com.xxxx.xxxx"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:installLocation="internalOnly"
      android:sharedUserId="xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
      android:sharedUserLabel="@string/shared_user_label">
```

In build.gradle I changed  versionCode 26 to versionCode 27 and  versionName "1.1.14" to versionName "1.1.15"

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 22
versionCode 27
versionName "1.1.15"}
```

When I compile and run the app it shows a popup dialog "Application Install failed" with the following message:

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Is there any way to upgrade the existing application by adding android: sharedUserId without uninstall? If yes, How?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932848/installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed-no-root

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `android:sharedUserId`, Android system will not allow to upgrade app, since `UID` got changed

alternate option is to use `contentProviders` to share the data between apps