# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] occurs on app debug, even after factory reset

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recieve the: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]` error when attempting to install my app to my phone. I attempted a factory reset and it still occurs. I have looked into many other posts containing this error and they often suggest a factory reset as a last resort. I have no idea why it will will not install. Please offer any help.

Comment: Is there a logcat to go with this?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the logcat window when I attempt to install the app.

Comment: Hmmm... Check the point of the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338242/eclipse-installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed .  Looks like using some reserved names/tokens can cause such an error.