# Error when trying to deploy application on phone from Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application but I have some problem while installing it on my phone from Android Studio. I get the follwing message :

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.luci.catalogrebuilt
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

In Logcat I get this messages:

```
08-17 16:20:57.815      766-972/? W/LicenseLogService﹕ log() is called by non admin
08-17 16:20:58.355      294-294/? E/SMD﹕ DCD ON
08-17 16:20:58.515    3447-3470/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ untagSocket(59) failed with errno -22
08-17 16:20:58.856      766-972/? W/LicenseLogService﹕ log() is called by non admin
08-17 16:20:58.856      766-886/? W/PackageManager﹕ verifying app can be installed or not
08-17 16:20:58.856      766-886/? W/PackageManager﹕ SELinuxMMAC.assignSeinfoValue
08-17 16:20:59.116      766-886/? W/PackageManager﹕ Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.luci.catalogrebuilt-1.apk
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: Did you try advices from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338242/eclipse-installation-error-install-failed-uid-changed ?

Comment: Yes, I did, nothing worked